# Remove JNDI data source configuration from spring based application that runs on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi, tomcat9

I have a requirement to remove the existing JNDI data source configuration from a spring based application that runs on tomcat.

Current configuration has this bean defined in the applicationContext xml :

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxdb"/>
  </bean>
```

this is the web.xml config :

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxxdb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

this is the tomcat context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resource auth="Application" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" maxIdle="30" maxTotal="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" name="jdbc/xxxdb" password="XXXX" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:db2://xxx:12345/xxxx;" username="xxxx"/>
</Context>
```

This whole JNDI setup needs to be removed. What is the best way to setup datasource other than this JNDI?

Comment: *This* is the best way. Why do you think it needs to be removed?

Comment: @user207421 As part of Springboot migration, Application SME wanted it removed :D